# Motorcycle missing Neutral when it's on

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, shifting

I'm new in this (Motorcycling). I've bought a motorcycle ([http://italika.mx/modelos/chopper/TC200/)](http://italika.mx/modelos/chopper/TC200/) I'm in Mexico. The issue is, that whenever the bike is off, I can shift really comfortable to N; though, when I turn it on, I've a hard time shifting to N from 1st Gear (it's almost impossible).

I want to know what would be the main issues with it. I've a few ideas, but I don't know if this happens often, or might be the model of the bike.
Does the clutch (plates) are worn and are causing this issue? Could be the cluth cable that isn't really tight (I've read that the cable shold have a little bit of play)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How old is the bike, meaning, not only the age, but how many miles (or KM if you prefer) are on the bike? When you describe it as being "hard" to shift, what do you mean by hard? I know on a lot of bikes, shifting into neutral can be tough until you're used to it. There may just be a "trick" to it which you aren't aware of yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paulster. The bike is almost 20,000 kms or 1,200 miles.

Hard to shift, is that whenever it is off, with slight force I can shift from 1st to Neutral. When it's on, I use a lot of force to find that sweet spot, but it just hurt my feet or shift to 2nd, just straight.

Some times, I get the N light on, when the motorcycle is turned on, but when I try to release the clutch, it just stalls, like some kind of a false Neutral.

Comment: Is the clutch hydraulic or cable actuated?

Comment: It's cable actuated.

Comment: While not a motorcycle expert (by any means), I'd suggest you try and adjust the clutch and see if it helps any. If the clutch isn't releasing all the way, it would make it harder to shift, especially into/out of neutral. If it's the typical adjustment I'm familiar with, you'd need to make the cable tighter (the small screw at the lever would need to be screwed out some). Do it in small increments (two to three threads at a time) to see if it makes any difference. If it doesn't, it's probably something internal to the clutch itself.

Answer (score 2):

As both previously commented, it was the slack on the clutch cable which gave the transmission a hard time finding Neutral. I backed off almost all of the slack and the first time I tried, it worked wonderfully, thanks to both of you for the advice.

Happy holidays.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so the community knows. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Two things that could help:

1) Try adjusting the clutch lever. Too much slack will result in a difficulty changing gears and finding neutral. You need to make sure the clutch is engaging enough to allow gear changes. There should be a wheel adjuster near the lever end of the cable, and possibly at the other end as well.

2) If you’re stationary, try rolling the bike forward or backward a few inches. This will rotate the output side of the transmission and can help the gears align better for the shift.